# Can not decrypt automysqlbackup files

Tags: openssl

I am trying to move a backup and decrypt it.

```
# openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in daily_db_2021-11-08_03h00m_Monday.sql.gz.enc -out daily_db_2021-11-08_03h00m_Monday.sql.gz
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
bad decrypt
140497360426304:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:610:
```

Runing with -nopad option to openssl doesn't result in an error but I still can not read the resulting file.

```
# openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in daily_db_2021-11-08_03h00m_Monday.sql.gz.enc -out daily_db_2021-11-08_03h00m_Monday.sql.gz -nopad
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.

# zcat daily_db_2021-11-08_03h00m_Monday.sql.gz | head

gzip: daily_db_2021-11-08_03h00m_Monday.sql.gz: not in gzip format
```

The resulting file is something but not gz.

```
# ls -lah daily_db_2021-11-08_03h00m_Monday.sql.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.1M Nov  8 14:09 daily_db_2021-11-08_03h00m_Monday.sql.gz
```

Encryption settings on my server:

```
# Do you wish to encrypt your backups using openssl?
CONFIG_encrypt='yes'

# Choose a password to encrypt the backups.
CONFIG_encrypt_password='***'
```

AutoMySQLBackup version 3.0

OpenSSL on both ends:

Server
openssl is already the newest version (1.1.1k-1+deb11u1).

Client
openssl is already the newest version (1.1.1k-1+deb11u1).

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct cipher when decrypting?

Comment: I am not sure. I just copied the decrypt line from the automysqlbackup documentation.

Comment: Facing same issue. Were you able to fix this @user6329530 ? Could you please post the answer if you know? Thanks!